# how does ping resolve to ipv4 on one machine, but ipv6 on another?

Tags: networking, sql-server, ipv6, linked-server, ipv4

**Background**
I have two environments, TEST and STAGE.  I use Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) with two linked 2008 SQL servers.  A SQL job runs every couple of minutes and everything works fine on TEST.  The SQL job does not run on STAGE.  The only difference I have been able to pinpoint is that ping resolves to an IPv6 address on STAGE, but an IPV4 address on TEST.  I suspect that MS DTC does not support IPv6.

**Question**
I have three computers:  testServer, stageServer, and productionServer.  If I ping productionServer from testServer I get a reply from 192.168.1.2.  If I ping productionServer from stageServer I get a reply from a long IPv6 address.  Both testServer and stageServer have IPv6 and IPv4 enabled.  Both testServer and stageServer use the same DNS servers, listed in the same order in the DNS tab.  Why are the ping resolutions of IP's different?

**TEST nslookup:** 
C:\Computer\me>nslookup
Default Server:  dnsServer.domain.net
Address: 192.168.1.47

> productionServer
Server:  dnsServer.domain.net
Address: 192.168.1.47

Name:  productionServer.domain.net
Address:  192.168.1.2
>

**STAGE nslookup:**
C:\Computer\me>nslookup
Default Server:  dnsServer.domain.net
Address: 192.168.1.47
> productionServer
Server:  dnsServer.domain.net
Address: 192.168.1.47

** dnsServer.domain.net can't find productionServer:  Server failed
>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your nslookup results, do you have the same domain suffix search list on both machines?  Hit the advanced button in the TCP/IP properties page, then go to the DNS tab.  Are there any differences there?

Also, why don't you give us the output of `ipconfig /all` from a command prompt?


--Christopher Karel

Comment: The DNS tab displays the same information for both systems "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes" is selected and "Append parent.." is checked too. But, ipconfig /all shows "domain.net" for Primary Dns Suffix on TEST, but STAGE shows no value for this field. So you have pinpointed a real problem. Considering the way both DNS tabs are configured is it safe to say that this is a DHCP problem?

Comment: Are both machines part of a domain?  I believe that field comes from your configured domain, as opposed to coming from the dhcp lease.  You can set it manually in the Advanced System Properties page, 'Computer Name' tab, then click the 'more' button.

Comment: Thanks Christopher.  I think they are both part of the domain, but I've gotto punt the issue to our network admin at this point as I don't have enough access to do anything else.  Very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Run nslookup on all sides? It sounds like your DNS entries difer, and stageserver is falling back on PNRP

Comment: Thank you for that useful information.  Results posted above.  How are those results even possible?

Comment: I'd vote you 1 up for this, but I dont have enough rating.